# SilverStripe visitor and permissions

Tags: authentication, permissions, roles, silverstripe

In SilverStripe is there any tutorial about users and content they can see after login, depending on their roles and permissions?

I would like users, after login, to see more content, but not to have access to the CMS.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some detail tutorials on this topic [Silverstripe User Help](http://userhelp.silverstripe.org/).

Of interest would be [Managing roles and permissions](http://userhelp.silverstripe.org/framework/en/for-website-administrators/managing-roles-and-permissions).

In setting Group permissions you can set if the users has permissions to all the CMS, parts of the CMS, or none of the CMS.

You can create a user Group that cannot access the CMS, but can view extra pages on the front end. To do this, when creating a new Group, on the *Permissions* tab deselect all the checkboxes.

Then you will want to set some pages that can only be accessed by logged in members. In the CMS select the page you want to only be viewed by logged in members. Go to the Page's Settings tab on the top right. On this screen you will see *Who can view this page?*. You can select either *Logged-in users* or *Only these people (choose from list)* and select the user Group in the input field.

You can control where a logged in user goes by extending the `MemberLoginForm`.

First create a `CustomLoginForm` class in *mysite/code/CustomLoginForm.php*.

**CustomLoginForm.php**

```php
class CustomLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm  {

    public function dologin($data) {
        if($this->performLogin($data)) {

            // Check if the logging in member has access to the CMS
            if(Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_CMSMain')) {
                // If they do, send them to the admin page
                $this->logInUserAndRedirect($data);
            }

            // If they don't, redirect them to whatever page you like. 
            // The following redirects the user to the home page
            return Controller::curr()->redirect(Director::baseURL());

        } else {
            if ($badLoginURL = Session::get('BadLoginURL')) {
                return Controller::curr()->redirect($badLoginURL);
            } else {
                return Controller::curr()->redirectBack();  
            }
        }      
    }

}
```

Call the `userCustomClass` function in your _mysite/*config.php* to set `CustomLoginForm` as your `MemberLoginForm. Add the following line to your _mysite/*config.php* file:

**config.php**

```php
Object::useCustomClass('MemberLoginForm', 'CustomLoginForm');
```

You could customise this to have the redirect page controlled through the CMS, even to be set for each user Group. It just needs a little code to add that in.

Comment: I already red that, but it seems there are roles and permission for part of cms which i want to hide.

Comment: That was a clue I was searching for

Comment: Do you know how to remove this notification: I'm sorry, but you can't access that part of the CMS. If you want to log in as someone else, do so below. I got it when I log as regular user who cant view CMS

Comment: @user1406647 - I've edited my answer with detail on how to do this.

Comment: I will try now, thnx.